# What is the exact meaning of @RestResource(exported=false) in Spring-Data?

Tags: spring, neo4j, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

I saw that the annotation `@RestResource(exported=false)` on a set of entities does not export this set when used with an spring-data-rest repository, but embeds the set of entities instead of rendering the url.

Is this the intended behaviour?

Isn't the attribute `exported=false` misleading, to say the least? What is the exact semantic of that annotation?

I use spring-data-rest with neo4j, i.e my project depends on spring-data-neo4j.